# General Question about number of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am wondering if there is any sort of algorithm , or if not, at least some general approach to the following;

Lets say we have two finite sets

$$A=\{a_1,a_2,…a_n\}$$ and $$B=\{b_1,b_2,…,b_m\}$$

and suppose that it may be that $m=n$ but that is not required. Assuming we know the size of m and n, is there a method to answer the following

How many surjections are there from A onto B and vice versa,

How many injections are there from A to B and vice versa,

and How many functions at all are there from A to B and vice versa.

Thanks for any input.

I will add a short worked example of one of the most simple cases, just to help get across what if I am looking for,

take

$$A=\{1,2,3,4\}$$ and $$B=\{a,b,c\}$$

There would be $3^4=81$ functions from A to B which can be seen easily.

For surjective from A onto B, we know one element of B must be mapped to twice. There is 3 choices for which element of B this is, and 6 choices for which two elements of A get mapped to the same B, and then 2 choices for the remains elements, i.e. 36 surjections.

Comment: Well, there are $n^n$ total functions (as there are $n$ values the function can take for each of $n$ slots).  And there are $n!$ surjections, as a surjection is just a permutation.  Injections need a little counting.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that the sets have the same number of elements.  It follows from that that injections are also surjections (and conversely) so we already have the count.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I edited though because It may not be the case that they have the same cardinality

Comment: Doesn't change much.  Total functions from A to B is now $m^n$.  If $m>n$ there are no surjections from A to B (and if $m<n$ there are no injections).  If $m>n$ then injections are given by an ordered subset of B of size n.  But there are m things that could go first, m-1 that could go second, and so on, so there are $m(m-1)(m-2)...(m-(k-1))$ injections.

Comment: Surjections from A to B, in the case n > m, seem to be a bit harder to count. Not sure why.  Probably just missing something.

Comment: @lulu oh. sorry. somehow I missed that :( I delete my comments.

Comment: @Quality.  Ok...in the case $n>m$ I think surjections are hard to count.  Interesting.  You need to count the number of ordered partitions of n into a sum of m positive integers.  I don't see how to avoid that.

Comment: @lulu for subjections, take a subset of $A$ of cardinality $m$ and map it bijectively onto $B$. and you should put your comments into an answer.

Comment: @user251257  Sure, but you still have to map the "extra" elements of A into B.  That messes up the count badly!

Comment: @lulu right ... it gets messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the discussion in the comments is getting involved, I'll summarize the conclusions here.

EDIT:  I have worked out the count in the final case and have included that here.

Total number:  The total number of functions $A\rightarrow B$ is $m^n$ because each of n slots can be filled with any of m things.

Case I: $n = m$

In that case surjections are the same as injections are the same as permutations, so there are n! of them.

Case II:  $m>n$

In this case there are no surjections.  An injection is defined by picking a subset, S, of B which has m elements and ordering it (the order corresponding to the order in A).  Thus there are $m(m-1)(m-2)...(m-(k-1))$ injections.

Case III $m<n$

In this case there are no injections.  To count surjections, we'll instead count functions which fail to be surjections (as we know there are $m^n$ functions in all this will suffice).  If a function is not a surjection then it maps to a proper subset. First, then, we remove the functions which map to a subset of size m - 1.  There are $\binom {m}{m-1}$ of these and there are $(m-1)^n$ functions that map to any given one. Alas, we have double counted (or, rather, double subtracted).  Accordingly, we have to add back those functions that mapped to a set of order m-2.  There are $\binom {m}{m-2}$ of these and there are $(m-2)^n$ functions that map to any given one.  Continuing in this manner we finally see that the number of surjections from A to B is: $$\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^{m-i}\binom{m}{m-i}i^n$$

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna look over this as well

Comment: I would check the surjection formula in some small case.  I am confident that the method is correct but I am quite tired and the probability of some error having crept in is sadly high.

Comment: A good tool for counting the number of surjections is the *Stirling numbers of the second kind*. You can take a look at this: http://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/bul945/HILT-P~1.PDF

Comment: @SolidSnake Thanks for the reference! I had never looked at the question before, it's surprisingly subtle.